# What's the meaning of "a cosmically fortuitous tie-in"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> Made for $108 million, "The Martian" received a publicity booster
>   earlier in the week when NASA announced it had found evidence of water
>   on the surface of Mars - a cosmically fortuitous tie-in for a movie
>   that celebrates NASA ingenuity.

What's the meaning of "a cosmically fortuitous tie-in"?

Is it just a pun? Can I just interpret it as a lucky or serendipitous connection or coincidence?

Tie-in has more than two meanings, and I'm not sure which one is more relevant.

1) A connection or association:

2) A book, film, or other product produced to take advantage of a related work in another medium

In addition to this, I have a poor grasp of how 'cosmically' and 'fortuitous' are combined and make a sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Tie-in* means **A *commercial/non-commercial* connection or association**.

*Cosmic* is used to describe things related with the universe as defined in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cosmic):

> **of or relating to the universe or outer space**

[*Fortuitous*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fortuitous) means:

> happening by chance
>
> **having or showing good luck**

"A cosmically fortutious tie-in" means the Nasa's announcement (there could be water in Mars, which is cosmically related) is a lucky coincidence/event that can help boost ticket sales of the movie (which shows good luck for the movie).

Comment: ['Cosmic'](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cosmic) also has the slang meaning of *exceptional*, via *'out of this world!'*. The writer could have said "Incredibly fortuitous...", but chose the space-related word because of the context.

Comment: @JHCL I agree with you. It can mean *immeasurably big* as in "This was disaster on a cosmic scale". But the meaning is also related with "the universe".

Comment: _Tie-in_ has a specifically commercial sense as a slang term. From Kipfer & Chapman, _Dictionary of American Slang_, fourth edition (2007): "**tie-in** _n_ **1** A connection : _I wonder if there's any tie-in with organized crime_ (1934+) **2** An item sold because of the existence of another item : _The book is a movie tie-in_ (1943+)." This mercantile aspect of the word _tie-in_ heightens the notion that the recent scientific evidence of water on Mars was _commercially_ serendipitous for the movie's makers.

Comment: @SvenYargs You don't agree that *commercially serendipitous* can be expressed in a more concrete way that *it can help boost ticket sales*?

Comment: I was writing in support of your interpretation, but offering a dictionary definition that (I think) makes the commercial overtones of "tie-in" more evident than does the definition you use at the beginning of your answer: "_Tie-in_ means _A connection or association_." I'm tempted to upvote your answer anyway, but I think it would be stronger with that sense of commercial connection/association made explicit at the outset.

Comment: @SvenYargs I edited my answer based on your comment as I don't disagree with your point. I am just worried that it might sound like NASA and the movie maker had a commercial arrangement to benefit each other. As far as I understand, it was just a coincidence without any **real** tie-in between them and it is only the movie that commercially benefited from the announcement.

Comment: without any **real tie-in** between them = without any contractual arrangement between them (?) IMO you have just added some confusion to the term tie-in by introducing: real tie-in

Comment: Your concern is valid. At the risk of being an unbearable pest, I recommend one further alteration of the opening line of your answer—from  "Tie-in means A commercial connection or association" to "Tie-in can mean a commercial (or noncommercial) connection or association." But I won't press this any farther. +1.

Comment: @Used_By_Already [Tie-in](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tie-in) 2.An authorized product based on a media property, such as a film or video game, by way of cross-promotion. There must be a contractual arrangement in this *tie-in*.

Comment: @SvenYargs I think the OP was confused with the 2 definitions of a dictionary. And I wanted to tell him/her that it doesn't necessarily mean No.2. Anyway, it looks clearer than my original answer. Thanks.